# improper integrability the following function

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

> Let $f:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
> \frac{1}{x^{2}}, & x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[1,\infty), \\
> -\frac{1}{x^{2}}, & x\in\mathbb{Q}^{c}\cap[1,\infty).
> \end{array} \right.$$

Then, is it true that $f$ is improper integrable on $[1,\infty)$?

Is it enough to guarantee that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\vert{f}\vert<\infty$?.

Or could the above statement be true, depending on whether it is Riemann or Lebesgue sense?

Give some comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not integrabe in Riemann sense because it is discontinuous everywhere. [Riemann integrable functions are continuous almost everywhere]. It is integrable in Lebesgue sense and the integral is $-1$. The function is equal to $-\frac  1 {x^{2}}$ almost everywhere and $\int_1^{\infty} -\frac 1{x^{2}}\, dx=-1$.